# wordpress does not translate my footer when changing language

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

good I want to translate my footer, when the user changes the language of my wordpress the footer is placed either in English or Spanish the text is translated, without using plugins, then I would like to know how to translate that text string according to the language.

I use the material-admin theme to style my admin dashboard

admin-footer.php

```
*/
    do_action( 'in_admin_footer' );
    ?>
    <p id="footer-left" class="alignleft">
        <?php
        $text = __( 'Desarrollado por Solutto Labs - Contact Us  <a href="%s">support@soluttoconsulting.com</a>' );

        /**
         * Filters the "Thank you" text displayed in the admin footer.
         *
         * @since 2.8.0
         *
         * @param string $text The content that will be printed.
         */
        echo apply_filters( 'admin_footer_text', '<span id="footer-thankyou">' . $text . '</span>' );
        ?>
    </p>
    <p id="footer-upgrade" class="alignright">
        <?php
        /**
         * Filters the version/update text displayed in the admin footer.
         *
         * WordPress prints the current version and update information,
         * using core_update_footer() at priority 10.
         *
         * @since 2.3.0
         *
         * @see core_update_footer()
         *
         * @param string $content The content that will be printed.
         */
        echo apply_filters( 'update_footer', '' );
        ?>
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

mtrl-functions.php

```
//change admin footer text
function mtrl_footer_admin () {
    
    /**
     * Change footer 
     * @solutto
     * by cesar
     * Since 31-07-2020
     */

    
    echo __( 'Desarrollado por Solutto Labs - Contactenos <a href="%s">support@soluttoconsulting.com</a>' );
}
```

Comment: You have just defined a function but did not make use of hooks to call the tag.

Comment: sorry I did not understand very well

Comment: Did you try this? https://www.isitwp.com/change-footer-text-in-wp-admin/

Comment: that changes my footer but I want it to change when the user changes language, what it says in Spanish, say it in English

Comment: I would be using LocoTranslate if I were you but since you don't want a plugin: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/288379/how-to-add-translation-for-a-string

Answer (score 0):

It was made with the following code

```
function mtrl_footer_admin () {
    
    $lang = get_locale();
    //var_dump($lang);
    if( $lang == 'en_US' || $lang == 'en_GB' ) {
        $text = __( 'By Solutto Labs - Contact Us <a href="mailto:support@soluttoconsulting.com">support@sollutoconsulting.com</a>', 'DOMINIO_AQUI' );
    } elseif( $lang == 'es_ES' ) {
        $text = __( 'Desarrollado por Solutto Labs - Contactenos <a href="mailto:support@soluttoconsulting.com">support@sollutoconsulting.com</a>', 'www.soluttoconsulting.com' );
    } else {
        $text = __( 'By Solutto Labs - Contact Us <a href="mailto:support@soluttoconsulting.com">support@sollutoconsulting.com</a>', 'DOMINIO_AQUI' );
    }
    
    echo $text;
    
    //echo __( 'Developed by Solutto Labs - <a href="mailto:support@soluttoconsulting.com">support@sollutoconsulting.com</a>', 'www.soluttoconsulting.com' );
}
```